# Does Electrum use Bitcore Apis as it's backend?

Tags: api, electrum, bip32-hd-wallets, seed, bitcore

Does Electrum use Bitcore Apis as it's backend or not?

If not, then what is the purpose of developing Electrum when Bitcore Apis provides all the features Electrum has (like HD wallets and master seeding)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrum uses the [electrum-server](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum-server) backend ([electrumx](https://github.com/kyuupichan/electrumx) is a newer variant)

In fact, electrum actually predates bitcore by about 2 years.

As to why there are multiple implementations of similar APIs and softwares, the answer is really "Why node?". Even the bitcoin node software has multiple implementations (Bitcoin Core and btcd, for instance).

This is a very open source friendly space, and it is generally actively encouraged to have multiple approaches to a problem.

Comment: Hi Raghav, so is it right to say that Electrum-api alone (after electrum-server is setup) provides all the basic methods to create wallets, add multiple addresses, create, initiate, send or cancel a transaction, etc.? Not to forget I also want to adjust txn fee during submitting the transaction. Is it all possible with Electrum-api or do I need to use Bitcore?

Comment: Electrum's APIs will help you view address balances/outputs, build a transaction, and broadcast it. Key generation, wallets, and signing are handled by the electrum frontend client, not by the server. They keys never leave the client device

Comment: Electrum frontend client such as?

Comment: Such as [Electrum](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum)

Comment: Does Electrum provides these apis? Can you please share a document link to it?

Comment: Electrum has an RPC interface, I believe, but I'm not familiar with it, never used it.

Comment: Okay thanks! Do you know any other API available that can do this by any chance? I want to setup Electrum-server and integrate Electrum client to my application.

Comment: Electrum will likely be your best option for a complete solution quickly, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

No

Electrum uses an Electrum Server as an API, which holds information on block headers, UTXOs and information on address balances and historical transactions. Electrum does all key management on the client and no critical user information are stored on the server.

Bitpay (Bitcore wallet) uses a Bitcore Wallet Service (that does wallet creation and key management) and that in turn uses the Insight API (which stores block / transaction data). Insight communicates with Bitcore which sits on top of Bitcoin.

Comment: So using Electrum, I can create multiple wallets with n number of addresses in each, right? Does Electrum api also provides a method to handle transactions such as initiate, send or cancel txn?

Comment: Sure it's a full spv wallet

Comment: Thanks Nikos! Do you know if Electrum provides any api?

Comment: API in what sense? It provides a full UI and command line option. Would you like to use it remotely or what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: We need to build a custom BTC wallet interface. Where user can create multiple wallets, address, send/receive transactions.

Comment: Also can we add custom fees for every transaction?

Comment: Fees are part of custom configuration. I think electrum offers rpc connectivity so you could build on top of that, i.e. having custom interface and sending rpc commands to electrum.